# how to emulate getDeclaredAnnotation in javax.lang.model.element TypeElement

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

Im writing an annotation processor and I have a annotation "a" with @Inherited.
This means that for any element "e" that represents a class "c" that extends the class on which my annotation is actually present I'll get `e.getAnnotation(a.class) != null` to be true - and well, this is the expectation.

I also was able to determine the highest class in hierarchy on which my annotation is actually present by:

```
private TypeElement getClassWhereAnnotationIsActuallyDefined(TypeElement e){
    if(e.getAnnotation(a.class) == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("method called on type: "+e.getQualifiedName().toString()+" which is not annotated @a !");
    }
    TypeElement superE = (TypeElement) processingEnv.getTypeUtils().asElement(e.getSuperclass());
    if(superE.getAnnotation(Secured.class) == null){
        return e;
    }else{
        return getClassWhereAnnotationIsActuallyDefined(superE);
    }
}
```

But I was not able to get the functionality to identify if on a given element I have actually declared annotation or not, that would work with more than one class in hierarchy having the annotation present (which is obviously possible with java reflection and the titular getDeclaredAnnotations method of a class).

//edit: I'm not thinking anymore today so maybe this one is obvious, but it would even be helpful to be able to detect if an annotatiotion has beed declared more than once in hierarhy at all as I'm as of yet even unsure if I want to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html#getDeclaredAnnotationsByType-java.lang.Class-

getAnnotationsByType( ...) uses it as well

Comment: This is java reflection - available only after you have things actually compiled (and running in a given vm). What I'm looking for is a way to get this information BEFORE classes are compiled (in the annotation processor).

Comment: so in this case it comes to my mind ANTLR or any product based on it ex.: https://javaparser.org/

Comment: Annotation processors already have an AST defined that they can traverse, but it doesn't look inside methods (for example), so is usually sufficient for cases like this. Additionally, it is already part of the compiler, and lets your visitor and code generation tools report errors, so that your maven/gradle/ant/ide tooling can correctly report to the user - better than creating a new tool from scratch.

Comment: maybe maven-procxessor-plugin (see java's support for source level annotation processors - javax.annotation.processing)